bscan wont update files records from a tape
I am recovering from a disaster. The OS from the old server has been destroyed.  I have to reload the catalog into an other bacula director catalog.
I have updated the Device ressource.  The files can now be listed using the bls command.
I use this command, that takes 4h30 hours:
bscan -d 99 -m -r -s -v -dt -d 99 -V MYLABEL -c /etc/bacula/bacula-sd.conf Ultrium-1 >> tmp.log &

The log files contains:
(.... Example of line in my 3,4 GB log file)
bscan: bscan.c:430-0 Record: SessId=253 SessTim=1706712893 FileIndex=533871 Stream=2 len=65536
(...)
Records added or updated in the catalog:
      1 Media
      1 Pool
      0 Job
      0 File
(END OF FILE)

How to make also the Jobs and Files to be added into my new catalog?
